# Which of queries is more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simply question, Which of queries is more efficient?

Query 1:

```
SELECT t1.NumUnicoEOL,
       t2.NumUnicoSoldadura
FROM   (SELECT NumUnicoEOL,
               NumUnicoSoldadura
        FROM   NumUnicoSoldaduraEOL) AS t1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT NumUnicoSoldadura,
                         Estado
                  FROM   NumUnicoSoldaduraEOLRechazada) AS t2
              ON t1.NumUnicoSoldadura = t2.NumUnicoSoldadura
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT t1.NumUnicoEOL,
       t2.NumUnicoSoldadura
FROM   NumUnicoSoldaduraEOL AS t1
       LEFT JOIN NumUnicoSoldaduraEOLRechazada AS t2
              ON t1.NumUnicoSoldadura = t2.NumUnicoSoldadura
```

1901268 rows.

Comment: Does your SSMS support execution plan and statistics?

Comment: They seem equivalent, most likely the optimizer will generate the same execution plan

Comment: You should try `execution plan` in [*SQL Query Analyzer*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216945%28v=sql.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and compare both query

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm . . . I'm tempted to answer:  the one that takes less time and uses fewer resources.  You know this by running the query and looking at the execution plan.

The reason I'm answering, though, is because the two probably have exactly the same execution plan.  Running a query has two phases.  The first is to parse and optimize the query.  The second is to execute it.

SQL Server has a good optimization engine.  Hence, it is going to ignore the needless subqueries.  Remember:  the code that gets run is very different from the code that you write.  The code that is run has also been optimized.

Comment: Sometime I read, *how you know which horse is faster?*. Well you put in on the track and make it run.

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have mentioned, check the execution plan to figure out which query has a low cost.

I expect query 2 to be faster assuming `NumUnicoSoldadura` is indexed on both tables. In the first query the risk is that subquery may load all data in memory for both tables followed by doing a comparison on `NumUnicoSoldadura`. Query Analyzers are smart and can mitigate such risk out, but double check by checking execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any more info, prefer Query #2.